# passing html to a function asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, html-helper

I have Html helper method, creating a check box along with some text, I pass.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty,@<text> <ul> <li> </li> </ul>           </text>}))


public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, ?? )
    {
        var chkBox = helper.CheckBoxFor(expression).ToString();

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<li>{0}</li><div>{1}</div>", chkBox, ??);
    }
```

What would be the signature of my method then. Some lambda/expression or something.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: Define it as an object, run it, and see what the runtime gives you as its type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you looking at [templated razor delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx). So in your case the helper might look something along the lines of:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression,
    Func<object, HelperResult> template)
{
    var chkBox = helper.CheckBoxFor(expression).ToHtmlString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
        string.Format("<li>{0}</li><div>{1}</div>", chkBox, template(null))
    );
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(
        x => x.SomeProperty,
        @<text><ul><li></li></ul></text>
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `string`. It's going into `string.Format`, so that gives you a hint.